# Google Contact Sync Problem

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-3, google-contacts

I bought Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (now with Kit Kat) about a year ago and used my Google account to sync contact, calendar, G-Mail, etc. Everything is working fine since I noticed contacts sync problem two weeks ago. Every time I make sync, **Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly.** message appears. I only have around 260 contacts. I researched and tried some solutions. But sync problem still exists. Some websites suggest to clear data of **Contact Storage** and I did. Nothing become except all my contacts were gone from my phone. Sync still doesn't work. I hate to do Factory Reset for such problem. I have searched many questions like mine at here but I can't find any solutions. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like it could be a connection problem. Are you on a Wi-Fi network? Can you access Gmail with other devices on the same network?

Comment: No. I use Mobile Data. I could sync on both Wi-Fi and Mobile Data before. I can sync other Google services, no problem.

Comment: You could try "resetting" your contacts app (*Settings→Apps,* look for "contacts", open, "clear cache" and "delete data" – just for safety, create a local backup before from within the contacts app using *Menu→Import/Export→export to SDCard*). Your contacts are still saved on Google's servers, and should be sync'd back soon (if not, you can always restore the backup).

Comment: I already did, @Izzy. Google contacts didn't sync back. I tried many ways. Nothing worked. I think Factory Reset is the only solution which I really hate to do.

Comment: Short of factory-reset (still leaving that as last resort) would be resetting your account, i.e. removing the Google account from your device, clean caches/data from all Google apps, re-add the Google account. To my knowledge, at least with Android 4.x and up, no data should be lost this way. If it works out, it saves you the factory-reset. If it doesn't, you'll factory-reset anyway...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, @Izzy. I will try again for every steps. Currently I exported contacts as vcard format from Google and imported to ph storage. It's not the way I prefer but it solves my problem temporarily.

Comment: Yes, that's a work-around. I didn't propose this, as when the sync starts kicking in again it might lead to duplicates – but if you imported it to your "local" contacts (as opposed to the "Google account"), that should be simple to solve then. Keeping my fingers crossed!

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://google.com/contacts from PC then log in and check your contact from there

Comment: How will this help?